# I cannot get the id in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

The problem is i want to get the id of the li and alert it, but it i cannot get the value of the id it just alerts an empty string. I'm stuck with this for almost 3 hours.

here is my code:

HTML:

```
<li id = "3" class = "projectlink">
  <a href="#">
      <div class = "row ellipsis"> 
        <i class = "fa fa-folder-open"> </i>
        <span>My Project</span>
      </div>
  </a>
</li>
```

JQUERY:

```
 $(document).on("click",".projectlink",function(){  
    var idx = event.target.id;
    alert(idx);
 });
```

Any idea what's the problem with this code?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to vsync! and i'm able to solve the problem. Just edited this code here and it really worked:

```
$(document).on("click",".projectlink",function(){  
  var idx = this.id;
  alert(idx);
});
```

Comment: I actually tried different values for the id but it doesn't seem to work also.

Comment: @vsync Thanks! that worked. I just wonder how?

Comment: Because `this` refers to the the object which the delegation matched, which was the specific '.projectlink` element which was clicked. This is how jQuery event delegation works. People want to be scored so badly they write answers to such simple questions. I prefer to just comment on the simple things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your javascript:

- Be sure to specify the `event` parameter in the click handler.
- Use `event.currentTarget` or `this` instead of `event.target`.
- *Recommendation* - Make `id`'s more complex, not just numbers.

```js
 $(document).on("click", ".projectlink", function (event) {
     var idx = event.currentTarget.id;
     alert(idx);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="item3" class="projectlink"> <a href="#">
      <div class="row ellipsis"> 
        <i class="fa fa-folder-open"> </i>
        <span>My Project</span>
      </div>
  </a>
</li>
```

The reason you need to use `event.currentTarget` instead of `event.target` has to deal with the event chain. When a `click` event gets fired the deepest element fires the initial trigger, and then the event is passed up to each parent element for them to handle.

In this example a `span` is getting clicked on (at least in my browser) and that event bubbles up to the `div.row.ellipsis` and then up to the `li#item3` and then up to `body` and so on. In other words, once all the `click` handlers for that element have been executed then the event gets passed up to that element's parent and the cycle continues.

In jQuery when a `click` event occurs it assigns 'event.target`to the initial element and the current element that has a`click`handler to`event.currentTarget`.

While you can use `this` to refer to the `event.currentTarget`, I don't recommend that for a few reasons. Mostly it is due to the danger of context in JavaScript. It is not hard to modify the context that a method runs in, just use `Function.prototype.bind()`, `jQuery.proxy()`, or (underscore/lodash's) `_.bind()`, etc. Since `this` can be changed, it's best to stick to the dedicated property on `event` that we can always trust. Likewise using `event.currentTarget` is much more descriptive that `this`, which makes it far more maintainable.

Comment: Wow! It seems like there are many alternatives. This code also worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to define `event` as callback parameter

```js
$(document).on("click", ".projectlink", function(event) {
  var idx = event.target.id;
  alert(idx);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="3" class="projectlink">d
  <a href="#" 4 id="">dd
      <div id = "5" class = "row ellipsis"> d
        <i class = "fa fa-folder-open" id = "6">dd </i>
        <span id = "f">My Project</span>
      </div>
  </a>
</li>
```

> The target property can be the element that registered for the event or a descendant of it. It is often useful to compare event.target to this in order to determine if the event is being handled due to event bubbling. This property is very useful in event delegation, when events bubble.

Taken from https://api.jquery.com/event.target/

**Update :**

So you need to use `this.id` because **[`event.target`](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/)** property can be the element that registered for the event or a descendant of it which doesn't have any `id` . `this` or **[`event.currentTarget`](https://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/)** refers the element that registered for the event

```js
$(document).on("click", ".projectlink", function() {
  var idx = this.id;
  alert(idx);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="3" class="projectlink">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="row ellipsis">
      <i class="fa fa-folder-open"> </i>
      <span>My Project</span>
    </div>
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: You don't _need_ to use `this.id`, you could just use `event.currentTarget.id`...

Comment: @PranavCBalan No problem. Also `this` can be a tricky thing in JavaScript, so that's why I tend to stay away from it if possible. ([See note here](https://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/))

Answer (score 0):

In your script, event.target.id is giving an error for "event is not defined". Modify your script to either include event in the call or not use event and work with this pointer as below:

```
jQuery(document).on("click",".projectlink",function(){  
var idx = this.id;
alert(idx);
});
```